# Is it possible to read cookie from legacy SSO and silently login to IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have a bunch of legacy MVC apps that are using a custom forms authentication provider.  The cookies are being saved under *.companydomain.com and all api's and identity server should have access to these cookies.

We are rolling out identity server for new apps.  We would like to give the legacy applications access to some of the new api's and we want the tokens to be under the users session.

Is it possible to have IdentityServer's silent login read the legacy cookie and build out a new session without the user having to do anything?

EDIT - So I guess the workflow would be.

1. User visits website and logs into legacy SSO.
2. Website sends legacy cookie to Identity Server to login and obtain access token.
3. Identity Server uses cookie to lookup auth from legacy SSO. Does not require any user interaction and finishes authentication flow.
4. If for some reason cookie is invalid or expired, Identity Server just 401's instead of redirecting to login.
5. Website can now provide access token when accessing newer api's.

Comment: “We would like to give the legacy applications access to some of the new api's and we want the tokens to be under the users session.” How would the user’s session containing the token help the legacy applications access the new APIs? Are the new APIs accessible through the access token? In which case the legacy applications still wouldn’t have access to the APIs unless the user has logged in, not requiring whatever is referred to as a “silent login” in this context

Comment: You would be better off (in every way) requiring your new users to log in to the new system the first time they access it.

Comment: Updated my post with what I think the login flow would be.  Yea what I am asking is can identity server be setup to validate that someone is authenticated in a different system and bypass user interaction.